# Multiply each row of an array with coefficients in list - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python an need help. This is the problem statement:

- I want to calculate the value of each of the three houses by multiplying the rows of the arraym X (each row representing one house) with the coefficients in list c, so for the first house: Price = (66x3000)+(5x200)+ (15x-50) + (2x5000) + (500x100) = 258.000
- Do not use numpy
- Print the price of the three houses

This is what I have so far:

```
# input values for three houses: 
#  - size [m^2], 
#  - size of the sauna [m^2], 
#  - distance to water [m], 
#  - number of indoor bathrooms, 
#  - proximity of neighbors [m]
X = [[66, 5, 15, 2, 500], 
     [21, 3, 50, 1, 100], 
     [120, 15, 5, 2, 1200]]

# coefficient values
c = [3000, 200 , -50, 5000, 100]

def predict(X, c):
    price = 0
    for i in range (len(X)):
        for j in range (len(X[i])):
            price += (c[j]*X[i][j])
        print(price)    
  

predict(X, c)
```

The output is
258250
334350
827100.

The program adds the value of the 2nd an 3rd hourse the the previous result, rather than returning each house's value. How can I fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about your calculation because `(66x3000)+(5x200)+ (15x-50) + (2x5000) + (500x100) = 258250` and not `250` which you have posted which means you are getting the correct result. Your requirement here is a dot product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line

```
price = 0
```

into the outer for loop:

```
def predict(X, c):
    for i in range (len(X)):
        price = 0
        for j in range (len(X[i])):
...
```